# Export View to a PDF

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

how can I call my ContentView() in this example. I don't want to print "Hello World" in the document. When you try to export, the document with "Hello World " is exported in the file location. How can I get ContentView() in the document instead of "Hello World"??  Can someone help me how to export my ContentView in this code. Any help please

```
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

struct MessageDocument: FileDocument {
    
    static var readableContentTypes: [UTType] { [.plainText] }

    var message: String

    init(message: String) {
        self.message = message
    }

    init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
        guard let data = configuration.file.regularFileContents,
              let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        else {
            throw CocoaError(.fileReadCorruptFile)
        }
        message = string
    }

    func fileWrapper(configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper {
        return FileWrapper(regularFileWithContents: message.data(using: .utf8)!)
    }
    
}

struct ExportView: View {
    
    @State private var document: MessageDocument = MessageDocument(message: "Hello, World!")
    @State private var isImporting: Bool = false
    @State private var isExporting: Bool = false
    //@Binding var showMenu: Bool
   // @Binding var selected: SelectedScreen
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           GroupBox(label: Text("Message:")) {
                TextEditor(text: $document.message)
               
            
            }
            
            
            GroupBox {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button(action: { isImporting = true }, label: {
                        Text("Import")
                    })
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button(action: { isExporting = true }, label: {
                        Text("Export")
                    })
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .fileExporter(
             isPresented: $isExporting,
             document: document,
             contentType: .plainText,
             defaultFilename: "Message"
         ) { result in
             if case .success = result {
                 // Handle success.
             } else {
                 // Handle failure.
             }
         }
        
    }
   
   
}
```

Comment: "how can I call my function ...", what function do you want to call? 
"...I don't want to print "Hello World" in the GroupBox", I don't see any print "Hello World" in the GroupBox.
What does "print View in a PDF" mean?

Comment: Suppose I want to call a View instead of a text message "Hello World". When you run the code, it will come up with a Text "Hello world" in the Text Editor.  I want my ContentView() to appear in the document instead of "Hello World".

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Were you able to figure out how to solve this? Or any confusion in the question?